# How to return multiple values from object function javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

i was wondering is it possible to return multiple values from a prototype object. I need to return the value of several arrays and call those at a later point. Below is an example of my code.. I can show a JSFiddle if needed..Thankss!!

```
 EmployeeObj.prototype.showEmployee = function(emPhoto0,emPhoto01){
     var employeePhoto = new Array();
     employeePhoto[emPhoto0] = new Image();
     employeePhoto[emPhoto0].src = "pics/taylor.jpg";
     employeePhoto[emPhoto01] = new Image();
     employeePhoto[emPhoto01].src = "pics/roger.jpg";

     var showPhoto1 = employeePhoto[emPhoto0];
     var showPhoto2 = employeePhoto[emPhoto1];

     return showPhoto1;
     return showPhoto2;
 };
```

Comment: What values would `emPhoto0` and `emPhoto01` have? On an `Array`, they should be integers - if they're not, you should use an `Object`.

Comment: emPhoto0 and emPhoto1 would be called later, those values would have 0, and 1, etc... to access the array elements (Photos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use multiple `return` statements in this way - only the first evaluated will happen, but you can return an *Object* or an *Array*, and access what you wanted from that.

```
EmployeeObj.prototype.showEmployee = function (emPhoto0, emPhoto01) {
    var employeePhoto = new Array();
    employeePhoto[emPhoto0] = new Image();
    employeePhoto[emPhoto0].src = "pics/taylor.jpg";
    employeePhoto[emPhoto01] = new Image();
    employeePhoto[emPhoto01].src = "pics/roger.jpg";
    var showPhoto1 = employeePhoto[emPhoto0];
    var showPhoto2 = employeePhoto[emPhoto1];
    return {'showPhoto1': showPhoto1, 'showPhoto2': showPhoto2};
    // or [showPhoto1, showPhoto2];
};
```

You would then access by

```
var em = new EmployeeObj(/* ... */),
    photos = em.showEmployee(/* ... */);
photos['showPhoto1']; // or photos['showPhoto2']
// or photos[0], photos[1], if you used the Array version
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks so much @ Paul, so basically you cant return multiple variables.. Only with objects or arrays... Lesson Well Learned :)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the 2 results in an object:

```
return { photo1: showPhoto1, photo2: showPhoto2 };
```

Comment: thanks im trying to figure out why did @Paul use '' around his object properties and in your code you didnt.. Will it work with in both cases??

Comment: @RicoPlasakoi Both are valid. All _Object_ keys are _Strings_. If you use a label, it is valid and converted to _String_, but you have the limitations of what you can write for labels (no spaces, no special chars).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot execute multiple `return` statements in one function. But you can return an array containing the results. In your case that's simple:

```
return employeePhoto;
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern answer to this problem is to use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) by returning an array, and destructure the array into variables on the caller side:

```
EmployeeObj.prototype.showEmployee = function (emPhoto0, emPhoto01) {
    ...
    return [showPhoto1,showPhoto2]
}

// Calling showEmployee
[showPh1, showPh2] = <Employee>.showEmployee(emPh0, emPh01)
```

Support for this pattern is slowly appearing now in browsers and node.js should have it very soon.

The coolest about this pattern is that it will allow us to implement an alternative error handling pattern that matches [Go lang Error handling](https://gobyexample.com/errors) through returning a value and an error.